# Execute As from sql connection string

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I'm trying to find a way to do the equivalent of an "execute as user" command from within a SQL connection string. I have a query coming from an external source that I can't modify and a database that already has security setup using execute as user. The only thing I can really modify is the connection string. I've been looking all over and am having trouble finding anything related in my searches.

Can something similar to "execute as user" be done within a connection string?

If yes, how?

Using SQL Server 2016 - SP1

Edit:
Users in a table have a number of roles associated with them. Each unique combination of roles has a user created (that can't login so you can't connect as that user and get access). That user has a schema that applies row level security so based on the user's role they can only see the data they are allowed. Using "execute as user = [auto generated user]" they impersonate the appropriate user with the unique permissions schema and thus only get back the data they are allowed to see. I will make a connection with a user and then need to do the equivalent of the execute as statement, but I can't modify the actual query so it needs to be done in the connection string.

Comment: Maybe connect as the user you want to impersonate (i.e. UserID and Password in the connection string)?

Comment: unfortunately, can't do that either... The users to impersonate are set as unable to login

Comment: So you want to execute some sql by impersonating a user that is not allowed to establish a connection? Does that sound like maybe something is not setup quite right??

Comment: See Edit. Database is setup just fine, but there are constraints in place that prevent modification of certain parts, thus the issue at hand.

Comment: @RandyBishop, In your question you ask `Can something similar ... be done within a connection string`, but then in your comment you say `unfortunately, can't do that` in reference to connection string impersonation.  Which one is it?  Do you want to do this in the connection string or not?

Comment: I need to impersonate a user, not log in as them and it needs to be done within a connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this via the connection string since you must already be connected in order to impersonate a user.

A connection string allows a user to connect (i.e., login) to a SQL Instance and therefore cannot be used by users that cannot login. Instead you'll have to connect as a user with login rights and then impersonate the user via [`EXECUTE AS USER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql).